# JUnit powermock throw exception IllegalAccessError:cannot clear JavaAgentClassRegister

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito

In java,use powermock to  test.There are 3 projects in my workspace. Two of them has been run without any problem.But last one throw Exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot clear JavaAgentClassRegister. Set method has not been called.
org.powermock.api.extension.agent.JavaAgentFrameworkRegisterImpl.clear(JavaAgentFrameworkRegisterImpl.java:41) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.clearFrameworkAgentClassRegister(PowerMockRule.java:84) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:78) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)

Same test code run in these projects.

I have been tried to copy other pom.xml configuration file to this project.But it still has this problem.

My test run on JDK8,Junit4 and PowerMock 2.0.9.I dont want to change my JDK.Is there any way to solve this problem? Or is there any configuration setting problem？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.